# The best constant in an integral inequality

Tags: integration, integral-inequality

I find a interesting inequality. Suppose that $y=y(x)$ is a differentiable function in $(0,L)$ and $y(0)=y(a)=0$. Consider the fraction
$$
F[y]=\frac{\int_0^{L}\vert y'\vert^2dx}{\int_0^L\vert y\vert^2 dx}
$$
where $y'=dy/dx$ and the denominator is nonzero since $y$ is nonezero function. So what's the low bound of $F[y]$? The best constant may be $\frac{\pi^2}{L^2}$, but how to prove it?

Comment: This looks like a job for Calculus of Variations.

Comment: It looks like the celebrated Poincaré-Wirtinger inequality...

Comment: @Michael:  Yes, good idea.

Comment: @Siminore: Yes, thank you for your hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is useful:[Wirtinger's inequality for functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger's_inequality_for_functions)